# What is the most efficient way to use lodash in a webpack based project?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I've tried adding in lodash by using lodash fp but I can't really understand it.  I'm assuming this is the best way to optimize lodash.  In my aurelia project I have

```
 import lofind from 'lodash/fp/find';
```

and then later on in my code I try using it

```
this.activeTrek = lofind(this.treks._embedded.get_user_treks, { 'default_trip': '1'});
```

This doesn't seem to work at all.  Is there some step I'm missing or a proper way to load in FP?  Is my find syntax wrong or something?

Answer (score 1):

The `find` function from FP lodash takes arguments differently from the normal `lodash.find`. Namely, it is [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and takes the iteratee first, data last. Their FP guide ([docs here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#mapping)) list the functions that are changed in this "capped iteratee arguments" way.

```
this.activeTrek = lofind({ default_trip: '1' })(this.treks._embedded.get_user_treks);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get that a try earlier but had slightly the wrong syntax.